# Preconditions.checkNotNull Android Null pointer Exception

Tags: android

I am trying to access my phone's internal storage to attach a file from internal storage. But anyhow I am getting an exception  "java.lang.NullPointerException: uri at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull". I have checked getCount method is not null. But still, i am facing this issue. what do I do?

```
**Code:**
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import net.gotev.uploadservice.MultipartUploadRequest;
import net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadNotificationConfig;

public class User_Issue extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText estoreissue, estorename, edescribe;
    Button b, btupload;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    TextView tvupload;
    private static final int IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 3;
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private EditText etCaption;
    private Uri filePath;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    //final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath()/";
    //final String uploadFileName = "";
    String upLoadServerUri = null;
    // Create string variable to hold the Edit\Text Value.
    String issue, storename, describe;
    // Creating Progress dialog.
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    String HttpUrl = "http://10.238.4.153/user_issue.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user__issue);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imupload);
        etCaption = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etupload);
        tvupload = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvupload);
        estorename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextstorename);
        estoreissue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextissue);
        edescribe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextdescribe);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btupload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonupload);
        tvupload.setText("Uploading File : 'mnt/Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath()/" + "'");

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        requestStoragePermission();
        // Creating Volley newRequestQueue .
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(User_Issue.this);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(User_Issue.this);

        btupload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             if(v==imageView)
             {
                 Intent in=new Intent();
                 in.setType("imupload/*");
                 in.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(in, "Complete action using"), IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
             }else if(v == btupload){
                 uploadMultipart();
             }
                    }
                });



                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait, while we upload your data to server");
                        progressDialog.show();
                        GetValueFromEditText();
                        // Creating string request with post method.
                        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HttpUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                                progressDialog.dismiss();

                                // Showing response message coming from server.
                                Toast.makeText(User_Issue.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        },
                                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                                        // Showing error message if something goes wrong.
                                        Toast.makeText(User_Issue.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    }
                                }) {
                            @Override
                            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                                // Creating Map String Params.
                                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                // Adding All values to Params.
                                params.put("storename", storename);
                                params.put("issue", issue);
                                params.put("describ", describe);

                                return params;
                            }

                        };

                        // Creating RequestQueue.
                        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(User_Issue.this);

                        // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
                        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                    }
                });
            }

            // Creating method to get value from EditText.
            public void GetValueFromEditText() {

                storename = estorename.getText().toString().trim();
                issue = estoreissue.getText().toString().trim();
                describe = edescribe.getText().toString().trim();

            }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                tvupload.setText("Path: ". concat(getPath(filePath)));
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void uploadMultipart() {
        String caption = etCaption.getText().toString().trim();
        //getting actual path
        String path = getPath(filePath);
        //uploading <code>
        try {
            String uploadID= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadID, HttpUrl)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("caption", caption) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        }
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor=null;
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        //cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();

        return path;
    }


    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return;

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
        }
        //And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
    //This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request
        if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

            //If permission is granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Displaying a toast
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
                Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

```
Logcat:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.mi.mikpiadmin, PID: 14255
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
                                                                               at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:60)
                                                                               at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:474)
                                                                               at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
                                                                               at com.example.mi.mikpiadmin.User_Issue.getPath(User_Issue.java:204)
                                                                               at com.example.mi.mikpiadmin.User_Issue.uploadMultipart(User_Issue.java:187)
                                                                               at com.example.mi.mikpiadmin.User_Issue$2.onClick(User_Issue.java:101)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: please add crash logs

Answer (score 0):

check Access permissions as required

Also make sure to use .checkDirExists() to see file availablity

Comment: I have these access permissions. still i am facing this issue. What do i do?

Comment: Verify file path as told u earlier

Comment: I am getting error in this " cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);"  & "String path = getPath(filePath);"

Comment: That means file and path do not match hence there is a null. Cold be file not found. File not created

Comment: I have solved it actually it was scope's issue. so that's why function was not properly called.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that `filePath` is not null before using it with `getContentResolver().query()`